# CANNOT Install external modules in Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, scikits, canopy

I have set Canopy as my default python compiler.
I want to install scikits modules, currently not available in Canopy Package manager. I have installed setup tools and easy_install, pip which points to Canopy installation ( which easy_install -> Canopy directory). But I cannot use either of them to download any of the above modules. 
More specifically fetching scikits.odes gives me this error log:

```
Cleaning up...

  Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/b3/cvy2g4393534zjsrgxgnmvch0000gn/T/pip_build_nick...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b3/cvy2g4393534zjsrgxgnmvch0000gn/T/pip_build_nick/scikits.odes

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1134, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 259, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b3/cvy2g4393534zjsrgxgnmvch0000gn/T/pip_build_nick/scikits.odes
```

Similar error logs were thrown for the other module installation attempts I had made.
Any suggestions? How can I fix this obvious bug?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that by installing `setuptools`, you have corrupted the version of `easy_install` that is already included in in the `distribute` package, which is part of Canopy. I have updated [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line) to emphasize this caution.

Please delete your Canopy User Python directory, `/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/` and restart Canopy to re-create it without the conflicting version of setuptools. Then `easy_install pip` from terminal, and try again.

I am not sure if this will suffice, but it will be a step at least.

Comment: Alright ran rm -r on /Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/ and  I restarted Canopy. I then ran "pip install scikits.odes" in the terminal. Still can't install the package. The bug report exceeds the character limit. Can ou give me an alternative way to send it?

Comment: You don't say that you ran "easy_install pip" as suggested. If not, you'll still be using the wrong pip. If that's not it, you can send a bug report to support@enthought.com

Comment: You 're right about it!
Now the installation needs a fortran compiler. Although I have g95 Gnu compiler and gcc installed, how can I make it "visible" to the installation process?